# Does Redis have Set with condition?

Tags: caching, redis, in-memory-database

I am looking for something like this:

```
update data
set data = new_data
where data.updated_at < new_data.updated_at
```

I can't find a solution for this problem,
The close one is to use `WATCH` but unfortunately it can't watch for specific `value` condition.

If redis can't do this, do you have any recommended in memory like Redis that support this feature?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Lua Scripts, using [`EVAL` command](https://redis.io/commands/eval)

Assuming you want to set both the update timestamp and the data value, and if no timestamp also set the values (for first-time set), the Lua script can be something like:

```
local updt = redis.call('GET', KEYS[1])
if (not updt) or (tonumber(updt) < tonumber(ARGV[1])) then 
    return redis.call('MSET', KEYS[1], ARGV[1], KEYS[2], ARGV[2]) 
else 
    return redis.error_reply('data is newer on server!')
end
```

You can invoke as:

```
EVAL "local updt = redis.call('GET', KEYS[1]) if (not updt) or (tonumber(updt) < tonumber(ARGV[1])) then return redis.call('MSET', KEYS[1], ARGV[1], KEYS[2], ARGV[2]) else return redis.error_reply('data is newer on server!') end" 2 dataUpdated data 1 initVal
```

You will find in Lua Scripts a very powerful tool to get the most out of Redis.